# Currency and affiliate in Price List

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I have some questions related to Price List in Demo site.

1. I found a "CURRENCY" in General tab and a "CURRENCY CODE" in Rules tab. What are the differences between these two CURRENCY?
2. In rule tab, there is a section: "LIMIT TO CERTAIN WEB REQUESTS" 
   Is this for Affiliate web sites only?

Thanks,
Giang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found a "CURRENCY" in General tab and a "CURRENCY CODE" in Rules tab. What are the differences between these two CURRENCY?

The one in the General tab is what currency should be returned when you retrieve a price from the pricelist. In the rules tab, that currency is used to match the price list for retrieval in the first place. You use the rules to obtain the price list (which can be based on a currency code) and then when you retrieve a price for a Sku from the pricelist, that price is in the currency that is in the General tab.

> In rule tab, there is a section: "LIMIT TO CERTAIN WEB REQUESTS" Is this for Affiliate web sites only?

No, you can use anything from the request URL you see in your browser.